# Create object with results of Enumerable.Where and add them to a list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to query a set I already have and create new objects from the results. I also want those objects to be added to an existing `LinkedList`.

What I have right now is

```
var results = fulldata.Where(x => x.ImportantData == ImportanceLevel.HIGH);
```

Now `results` contain a set of data objects defined liked this :

```
public class DataObject{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int DataType;
}
```

I'd like to write with the same syntax (as the Where() list comprehension method) an equivalent of the following code :

```
var prunedResults = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
foreach(var res in results){
  if(res.DataType == DataTypeSpecial){
    prunedResults.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(res.x, res.y));
  }
}
```

I'm pretty new to "modern" C# so if you could also define terms used here, it would help me to google further answers. What I mean is that this seems to be called LINQ and the Where() call is using a lambda expression, but I could be somewhat wrong.

Comment: R# should suggest conversion automatically... You really looking for documentation on `Enumerable.Select` (assuming you've already found that `LinkedList`'s constructor takes enumerable and you already have `Where` worked out)..

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Not everyone uses resharper :)

Comment: I've been working on cpp for years now and most of my "on-the-side" projects were in python so I know the language can do stuff like this since I've browsed some code over the years, but I never got to write it myself

Comment: In terms of your more general question to the end, I think you might want to read through the method list for `Enumerable` for a start. Doing the same for `Queryable` and noting how they complement each other would be no bad thing either.

Comment: Is there a reason why this is downvoted? I care more about asking good questions than rep, but this seemed legit to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var prunedResults = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
//do other stuff to prunedResults
prunedResults.AddRange(results.Where(x => x.DataType == DataTypeSpecial)
    .Select(res=> new KeyValuePair<int, int>(res.x, res.y)));
```

Comment: AddRange seems promising, but how will it know how to convert from DataObject to KeyValuePair ?

Comment: @Eric you could project it with Select. e.g. `.Where(x => ...).Select(res=> new KeyValuePair<int, int>(res.x, res.y))`

Comment: `LinkedList<T>` has no `AddRange`, `List<T>`, however, does.

Comment: Ok thanks, I got it to work with the Select, which really was what I was after.

Comment: If you could update the answer body with  the Select, I'll accept it